# Get gzip file from endpoint, extract data and add to database improvements

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

I currently have a script that fires a request to an API endpoint which returns a `csv.gzip` file - which roughly contains 75,000 rows and 15 columns. I download this files to the webserver disk storage, unzip the file to `.csv` and then loop through every row and add the data into my database. Finally deleting the files saved to disk. The process currently takes between 5 and 10 minutes to complete.

I'm sure there is areas of improvement but not sure how to implement them. Some of them is:

1. Save csv data to variable rather than on disk.
2. Bulk import the data into my database.

I'm sure there are other improvements to be made, so any advice would be appreciated.

```py
response = oauth.get(realm)

content = ET.fromstring(response.content)
coded_string = (content.find('.//pricefile'))
decoded_string = base64.b64decode(coded_string.text)
with open('test.csv.gzip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(decoded_string)
    with gzip.open('test.csv.gzip', 'rb') as f_in:
        with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        pricing.objects.update_or_create(
            product_id=row[0],
            date=datetime.now(),

            defaults={
                'average_price': Decimal(row[1] or 0),
                'low_price': Decimal(row[2] or 0),
                'high_price': Decimal(row[3] or 0),
                ...
            })

os.remove('test.csv')
os.remove('test.csv.gzip')
```

Comment: maybe first use module `time` to measure time between executed functions to see which one tak time.

Comment: some databases can import directly from file CSV. You didn't show how you input data to database but usually there is `executemany()` to run `INPUT` on many data at once

Comment: you can use `io.String()` to create file-like object in memory and you don't have to use files on disk.

Comment: What needs to be improved?  Is there a problem to be solved (like how slow it is), or are you just looking for things to nitpick?

Comment: @furas data is added to the database via `pricing.objects.update_or_create(` section of the code. @jjanes a bit of both really.

Comment: Use `psycopg2` [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) functionality to [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) the data to a temporary table and then use `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT` from here [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) to move data from temporary table to final table. I'm betting you will a see dramatic decrease in the overall time.

Comment: While shuffling the data repeatedly between memory and disk is surely not great, the real bottleneck is almost surely in pricing.objects.update_or_create.  Look for a bulk-loading alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using `psycopg2` directly. `names.csv` is derived from the US Social Security names database and has 260000 lines by four columns.

```
import psycopg2
import csv
import time

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432) 
cur = con.cursor()   

with open("/home/aklaver/software_projects/test_data/data_sets/names/names.csv", newline="") as csv_file:
   t1 = time.time()
   cur.execute('create temp table names_csv_tmp(name varchar, rank integer, gender varchar, year integer, PRIMARY KEY(name, gender,year))')
   cur.execute('create table if not exists names_csv(name varchar, rank integer, gender varchar, year integer, PRIMARY KEY(name, gender,year))')  
   cur.copy_expert("COPY names_csv_tmp FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER", csv_file)
   cur.execute("insert into names_csv select * from names_csv_tmp ON CONFLICT (name,gender, year) DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name, gender=EXCLUDED.gender")
   cur.execute("drop table names_csv_tmp")
   con.commit()
   t2 = time.time()
   print(t2 - t1)
```

For first run where the table `names_csv` was empty and the `INSERT` was just inserting all the the records from `names_csv_tmp` the timing was `3.66` seconds.

For the second run where the `ON CONFLICT` triggered updates the run time was `7.29` seconds.

**UPDATE**

To clarify `ON CONFLICT` relies, per [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT), on there being a "..unique violation or exclusion constraint violation error." that triggers the alternate `ON CONFLICT` action to the original `INSERT` action.

Comment: The table that I am coping to has two extra columns. id which is a UUID, and a date column. When I try to add `insert into x select uuid_generate_v4(), CURRENT_DATE, * from y on conflict (date, product_id)...` I get the following error: `there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`

Comment: I managed to get it working by creating an index on `date, product_id` and it's taking around 50-70 seconds for my local database. Will try production database shortly.

Comment: This seems to have reduced it to 5 seconds. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added updated an UPDATE to mention that there needs to be a unique/exclusion constraint in place to get `ON CONFLICT` to work.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). Something like:

```
pricing.objects.bulk_create(
    [
        pricing(
            product_id=row[0],
            date=datetime.now(),
            average_price=Decimal(row[1] or 0),
            …
        ),
        for row in reader
    ],
    update_conflicts=True,
    update_fields=["date", "average_price", …],
    unique_fields=["product_id"]
)
```

Comment: Hello, when I try this I get `_bulk_create() got an unexpected keyword argument` for `update_conflicts`, `update_fields`, and `unique_fields`. It works without them but the doesn't update existing records.

Comment: I think this not working for me as I am using Django 3.2. and these argument seem top have been introduced in 4.x.